# Read tabs separated file into arrays in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, file, tabs, io

I have file like this:

int1--tab--int2--tab--int3--tab--int4--tab--newline

int1--tab--int2--tab--int3--tab--int4--tab--newline

int1--tab--int2--tab--int3--tab--int4--tab--newline 
...

I want to save each row in to an array. I mean all int1 in to an array and want to do the same whit int2 int3 ...

I realy dont know how to do it please help me

I already try read it line by line

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string line;
while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    int a, b;
    if (!(iss >> a >> b)) { break; } 

}
```

Comment: Not a bad attempt.  Do you know there are always 4 columns?  Do you know about vector<int> ?

Comment: is the "--" in your file a separator you added to make it clear, or are there really "--" in the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had the right idea using a stringstream. Since code to read delimited files is likely to be used again, you may find it useful to put this into class. Here's an excerpt from my personal delimited FileReader class:

```
bool FileReader::getrow(RowMap &row){
    std::string line = "";
    if(std::getline(filehandle,line)){
        std::stringstream line_ss(line);
        std::string column = "";
        unsigned int index = 0;
        while(std::getline(line_ss,column,delimiter)){
            if(index < headers.size()){
                row[headers[index]] = column;
                index++;
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Where RowMap is a typedef of:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string>
```

And headers is a typedef of:

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> RowHeadersVector;
```

And should have your column names:

```
RowHeadersVector headers;
headers.push_back("column_1");
```

In my example, I'm using a map of string to string, but you could easily change it to:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string,int>
```

The benefit of using a map like this is self documented code:

```
row["column_1"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks quite reasonable. If you know the number of columns, you can just create suitable arrays and add them:

```
std::vector<int> array, barray, carray, darray;
std::istringstream lin;
for (std::string line; std::getline(infile, line); ) {
    lin.clear();
    lin.str(line);
    if (lin >> a >> b >> c >> d) {
        aarray.push_back(a);
        barray.push_back(b);
        carray.push_back(c);
        darray.push_back(d);
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "WARNING: failed to decode line '" << line << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that you've done the hard part and are stuck on what seems to me to be the easy part.

Just replace `a` and `b` with arrays and an index.

```
int a[100], b[100];
int count = 0;
std::string line;
while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    if (!(iss >> a[count] >> b[count])) { break; } 
    ++count;
}
```

At the end of this loop `count` will tell you how many items you've added to the arrays. Of course this code will crash if you try to add more than 100 items to the arrays. I'll leave you to think about that.

Comment: What if a whitespace appears in a column?